# Io language 'apply arguments'

Tags: iolanguage

In the Io programming language, is there an equivalent to lisp's apply function.

So for example I have a method to wrap writeln :

```
mymeth := method(
              //do some extra stuff

             writeln(call message arguments))
)
```

At the moment this just prints the list, and doesn't evaluate it's contents as if they were it's own args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to that person who suggested evalArgs (not sure where your comment went).

Anyway that has resolved for my situation, although unfortunately not in general I guess.

You can achieve what I describe by doing :

`writeln(call evalArgs join)`

This evaluates all arguments, and then joins the results into a single string.

Answer (score 3):

> is there an equivalent to lisp's apply function?

Have a look at [`perform`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/perform) & [`performWithArgList`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Object/performWithArgList) methods.

To step back a bit you can replicate Lisp's `FUNCALL` in a few different ways in Io:

#### 1 - Passing a function ie. block():

```
plotf := method (fn, min, max, step,
    for (i, min, max, step,
        fn call(i) roundDown repeat(write("*"))
        writeln
    )
)

plotf( block(n, n exp), 0, 4, 1/2 )
```

#### 2 - Passing a message:

```
plotm := method (msg, min, max, step,
    for (i, min, max, step,
        i doMessage(msg) roundDown repeat(write("*"))
        writeln
    )
)

plotm( message(exp), 0, 4, 1/2 )
```

#### 3 - passing the function name as a string:

```
plots := method (str, min, max, step,
    for (i, min, max, step,
        i perform(str) roundDown repeat(write("*"))
        writeln
    )
)

plots( "exp", 0, 4, 1/2 )
```

So from all this you could create a Lisp `APPLY` like so:

```
apply := method (
    args := call message argsEvaluatedIn(call sender)
    fn   := args removeFirst
    performWithArgList( fn, args )
)

apply( "plotf", block(n, n exp), 0, 4, 1/2 )

apply( "plotm", message(exp), 0, 4, 1/2 )

apply( "plots", "exp", 0, 4, 1/2 )
```

Comment: That's fairly useful. Do you know how to apply a dynamic list of arguments to a block of unknown arity?

Comment: @mcandre: Sorry only just seen your comment.  Not 100% sure what you're after because above may provide what you're looking for?   I've created a more concise gist which will hopefully help: https://gist.github.com/1334070

Comment: Steve Dekorte [gets it](https://github.com/mcandre/io/commit/6ee2f4a0349cebb5365d0fbfb2259b2f4b62022b). :) And here's an [example](https://github.com/mcandre/iocheck) of its use.