# How do I apply a dynamic list of arguments to a block in Io?

Tags: lambda, block, apply, iolanguage

I'm writing a unit test framework ([IoCheck](https://github.com/mcandre/IoCheck)). There will be a `forAll` method which accepts a property, such as `isEven`, which returns whether an integer is even, and a list of generators `list(genInt)`.

The syntax will look like this:

```
isEven := block(i, i % 2 == 0)

forAll(isEven, list(genInt))
```

Since not all integers are even, the output will look like:

```
***Failed!
57
```

`forAll` will call the generators, storing the values in a list, and applying the values to the property 100 times. If the property returns false, the tests case is considered a failure, and the offending values will be printed to the screen.

In order to do this, `forAll` must accept a block of unknown arity and call it with a list of arguments. I don't know how to do this.

Note: This is NOT the same as [Io language 'apply arguments'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419779/io-language-apply-arguments), because in that case the code knows the arity but not the function. In this case, the code will know neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: `Block callWithArgList` has been added to the Io master branch.

[Paragon](http://blurgle.blogspot.com/2006/08/converting-lists-into-messages-and.html) has the answer. Add this snippet to your code, and you'll be able to send any Block object the message "callWithArgList".

```
getSlot("Block") callWithArgList := method(argList,
    getSlot("self") doMessage(argList asMessage setName("call"))
)
```

It works like Lisp's `apply` function.